# Regex for MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to select a field based on it meeting one of 3 criteria... and I'm not sure how to do this.  I think a RegExp is probably the best method buy I'm unfamiliar with writing them.

Say I have the integer 123, I would like to match the following cases:

123 (thats 123 only with no spaces or other numbers after it)
123-10/12/2007 00:00 (thats 123 with a hyphen and a date, or actually it could be anything after the hyphen)
123_1014859 (thats 123 with an underscore, or again anything after the underscore)

Is there a way to do this using MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex is plausible, but it's not the best performing option.  The last comparison put MySQL's regex support as being par with wildcarding the left side of a `LIKE` statement -- works, but the slowest of every option available.

Based on your example, you could use:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
 WHERE t.column LIKE '123-%'
    OR t.column LIKE '123_%'
```

Another alternative, because `OR` can be a performance issue too, would be to use a UNION:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE a
 WHERE a.column LIKE '123-%'
UNION ALL
SELECT b.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE b
 WHERE b.column LIKE '123_%'
```

`UNION ALL` will return all results from both tables; `UNION` removes duplicates, and is slower than `UNION ALL` for that fact.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from foo where bar regexp '^123-|_'
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using regex inside a SQL statement. Someone can correct me if I am wrong, but MySQL has to use another engine to run the regex.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE field like "123" 
    OR field LIKE "123-%" 
    OR field like "123_%";
```

Comment: I don't know that MySQL uses another engine -- SQL Server 2005+ requires CLR (which offloads to .NET) if you want regex support...